# How do I add a delete route with nested resources rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, crud

Todo has many Items. I am trying to add a link to delete an item from the todo list. I have tried variations to find an item by id under the todo list and I can't figure it out. This is the most recent error based of the the changes I made. I don't know how to fix this.

Error message: `No route matches [DELETE] "/todos/6/items"`

Todo Controller:

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js
  before_action :set_todo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /todos
  # GET /todos.json
  def index
    @todos = Todo.all
    @todo = Todo.new
  end

  # GET /todos/1
  # GET /todos/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /todos/new
  def new
    @todo = Todo.new
    #3.times{@todo.items.build}
  end

  # GET /todos/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /todos
  # POST /todos.json
  def create
    @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)
    #@todo.items.build

    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo.save
        format.html { redirect_to todos_path, notice: 'Todo was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @todo }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @todo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /todos/1
  # PATCH/PUT /todos/1.json
  def update
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @todo.update(todo_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @todo, notice: 'Todo was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @todo }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @todo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /todos/1
  # DELETE /todos/1.json
  def destroy
    @todo.destroy
    @todo.items.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to todos_url, notice: 'Todo was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_todo
      @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def todo_params
      params.require(:todo).permit(:title, :completed, items_attributes: [:content,:completed, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

Items Controller:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_todo
  respond_to :html, :js

  # GET /items
  # GET /items.json
  def index
    @items = Item.all
  end

  # GET /items/1
  # GET /items/1.json
  def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /items/new
  def new
    @item = @todo.items.build
  end

  # GET /items/1/edit
  def edit
    @item = Items.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /items
  # POST /items.json
  def create
    @item = @todo.items.build(item_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.html { redirect_to [@todo,@item], notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /items/1
  # PATCH/PUT /items/1.json
  def update
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.update(item_params)
        format.html { redirect_to [@todo, @item], notice: 'Item was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /items/1
  # DELETE /items/1.json
  def destroy
    @todo.items.destroy
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @item.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @todo, notice: 'Item was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_item
      @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_todo
      @todo = Todo.find(params[:todo_id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:content, :todo_id)
    end
end
```

Routes:

```
        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                              Controller#Action
    todo_items GET    /todos/:todo_id/items(.:format)          items#index
               POST   /todos/:todo_id/items(.:format)          items#create
 new_todo_item GET    /todos/:todo_id/items/new(.:format)      items#new
edit_todo_item GET    /todos/:todo_id/items/:id/edit(.:format) items#edit
     todo_item GET    /todos/:todo_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#show
               PATCH  /todos/:todo_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#update
               PUT    /todos/:todo_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#update
               DELETE /todos/:todo_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#destroy
         todos GET    /todos(.:format)                         todos#index
               POST   /todos(.:format)                         todos#create
      new_todo GET    /todos/new(.:format)                     todos#new
     edit_todo GET    /todos/:id/edit(.:format)                todos#edit
          todo GET    /todos/:id(.:format)                     todos#show
               PATCH  /todos/:id(.:format)                     todos#update
               PUT    /todos/:id(.:format)                     todos#update
               DELETE /todos/:id(.:format)                     todos#destroy
```

and my index page:

```
<h1>Listing todos</h1>
<ul>
  <% @todos.each do |todo| %>
    <li><%= link_to todo.title ,edit_todo_path(todo)%></li>
      <ul> 
        <% todo.items.each do |item| %></br>
          <li><%= item.content %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Delete Item',todo_item_path(item.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this item?"} %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
  <% end %>
</ul>


<%= link_to 'New Todo', new_todo_path %>
```

Comment: try like this <%= link_to "delete", [@todo, item], :method  => :delete %>

Comment: I tried that first, it gives me `ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"items", :id=>"6", :todo_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:todo_id]:` Idk why it needs the todo_id or why its trying to route to show?

Comment: sorry ..remove @ symbol and try <%= link_to "delete", [todo, item], :method => :delete %>

Comment: Thank you, I kept trying @todo and some other variation of that. Put it as an answer and can you tell my why [todo,item] works?

Comment: Me being beginner ..i am not quite sure of how it exactly it works ..but i knew that this technique works for nested resources and i have been using it quite some times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try using `<%= link_to "delete", [todo, item], :method => :delete %>`.

Comment: Just to explain why you need this. Take a look at this line in your rake routes output: `DELETE /todos/:todo_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#destroy`. That's the route you're trying to hit, and as you'll note, it takes both a `todo_id` and an `item` ID (extracted from the params as simply `params[:id]`). So you need to give both ids in your path helper. Your original solution just gave the todo_id, but since you're trying to delete an __item__ from a todo, you needed that item's id as well. The implicitly called path helper extracts both ids from the array Rahul has you use.