# deleting element from nested form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hello i have my routes in rails of this way:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :socials
  end
```

this is my models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :socials, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :socials
end

class Social < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

here is my controller of socials for destroy a row in the table socials, i dont need delete the user, only need delete one row in socials with the id from a form nested :

```
<div class="container">
<%= form_with(model: @user, local: true) do |f| %>
 ...
  Social Media
    <div class="container m-3">
      <%= f.fields_for :socials, {class: 'inline-block m-3'} do | social |  %>

        <%= social.label :name, class: 'inline-block m-3'%>
        <%= social.text_field :name %>
        <%= social.label :link, class: 'inline-block m-3'%>
        <%= social.text_field :link %>
        *<%= link_to 'Delete', user_social_path(@user.social.id), method: :delete %> ->
        <hr>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

and then with this link_to i wanna delete the row when i hit on delete of socials table, how can i do this? i am using 6.1.2.1 version of ruby and rails

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26108205/how-do-i-add-a-delete-route-with-nested-resources-rails-4

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not delete using link..

Nested forms already support options to delete a row, What you need to do is that just pass one more key value pair in socials which is `_destroy: true`

And in the controller side just allow `_destroy` in strong params,

In model define it like `accepts_nested_attributes_for :socials, allow_destroy: true`

And you can play some trick on UI to make it more attractive.

- Define a hidden field for `_destroy` with default option as false.
- Add button for delete with a Javascript on click event.
- On click of the button hide that row and change value of `_destroy` field to `true`

Now when you will save/update it, It will be deleted.

References: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to "delete", [@user, @user.social], :method => :delete %>
```